# Pandas: Filling NaN values in dataframe with monthly mean

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe I am working with is as follows:

```
        date                AA1  AB2  AC3  AD4
0       1996-01-01 00:00:00 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1       1996-01-01 01:00:00 NaN  19.2 NaN  NaN
2       1996-01-01 02:00:00 NaN  16.4 NaN  NaN
3       1996-01-01 03:00:00 NaN  23.5 NaN  NaN
4       1996-01-01 04:00:00 20.4 NaN  NaN  NaN
...     ...                 ...  ...  ...  ...
219164  2020-12-31 20:00:00 13.4 NaN  23.0 26.6
219165  2020-12-31 21:00:00 14.2 NaN  19.6 28.3
219166  2020-12-31 22:00:00 13.5 NaN  17.9 20.5
219167  2020-12-31 23:00:00 NaN  NaN  16.7 20.7
219168  2021-01-01 00:00:00 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

These are hourly data readings taken from different sensors from the year 1996 to 2021.

My goal is to be able to fill the NaN values with the monthly mean for each of the columns based on the date.

I have tried grouping the data and getting the monthly means for the group, though I am not sure where to go from here to transfer the grouped means to the original, larger dataframe, filling in some of the NaN values.

```
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
tem = df.groupby(['year', 'month']).mean().reset_index()
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this, with less indices because of the grouping:

```
    year   month  AA1   AB2   AC3   AD4
0   1996    1     20.1  18.3  NaN   NaN
1   1996    2     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   1996    3     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   1996    4     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4   1996    5     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
... ...     ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
296 2020    9     NaN   NaN   15.7  20.2
297 2020    10    NaN   NaN   15.3  19.7
298 2020    11    NaN   NaN   26.7  25.9
299 2020    12    NaN   NaN   24.6  25.3
300 2021    1     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Any advice on how I can implement this would be helpful. In the end, I need the original dataset indices, dates and columns, but with the NaN values filled with the means calculated from the monthly groups. The months with all NaN values can be ignored for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your date column is of type `datetime64` or equivalent:

```
df['AA2'] = df['AA2'].fillna(df.groupby(df.date.dt.month)['AA2'].transform('mean'))
```

Or looping over all your columns (except the date column):

```
for col in df.columns.drop('date'):
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df.groupby(df.date.dt.month)[col].transform('mean'))
```

If you only want the mean of the month in that specific year, add `df.date.dt.year` to the group by function:

```
for col in df.columns.drop('date'):
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df.groupby([df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month])[col].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly as I needed it to.